# Errors in code during the the creation downloader of search page in python

Tags: python, search, local-storage

The scope of the project is to download the results of a search page locally with the names page 1,page 3 etc. First, was made a code which just downloads the results of one page locally. The code is in follow lines and its written to compare the modification evolution and the problems which are appeared:

```
import urllib.request as urr
from urllib.parse   import quote
from urllib.request import urlopen
response=urr.urlopen('http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=%CE%A0%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%B2%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BD'+quote('περιβαλλον') )
page=response.read()
print(page)
f=open('C:\page.html',"wb")
f.write(page)
f.close()
```

So the evolution of this set of code must be find in the result of search  for example the Greek word "υγεια" if you type in the address bar [http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=υγεία&page=3](http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=%CF%85%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%B1&page=3)
the third page of the health results will appear (numbering starts at 1). So the parameter q = ALPHABETICAL indicates the question while page = INTEGRAL indicates the results page. The follow block of code try when we want to research a word-for example the word "περιβαλλον" to:a)The start page, even if we type 2 b) the final page, even if we type 4
The program, in this example -as written previously  will create 3 files with names page2.html,page3.html,page4.html The code is :

```
import os, sys
import re
import urllib.request as urr
from urllib.parse   import quote
from urllib.request import urlopen
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#coding: UTF-8
response=urr.urlopen('http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=%CF%85%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1'+quote('υγεια') )
#response=urr.urlopen('http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=υγεία&page=3'+quote('υγεια') )
#page=response.read()
#page=findall"(?!\")http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=περιβάλλον&page=*(?=\")", response
pagea=print(re.findall("(?!\")http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=περιβάλλον&page=*(?=\")", str(response)))
pagea=response.read()#.decode('UTF-8')#
print(pagea)
f=open('C:\pagea.html',"wb")
for i in pagea:
    f.write(pagea)
    f.close()
```

In the comments is part of code which try to resolve the issues without any result. Any  idea to sort and save result is welcome

[image]

The main problem is that it not appeared a way to create all the pages(page1,page2 etc)

Comment: are you sure that `response` is a string or bytes-like object?

Comment: response includes the results of the first search page after the search

Comment: but is it a string or some kind of a `Response` object? I think you need to use `str(response)` in that `findall` function

Comment: Put the regex in a variable and print it to see if anything is wrong with it. Then as @Matiiss suggested, try to print response to see its type.

Comment: @PtitXav nothing is wrong with the regex in the sense that it doesn't raise any exceptions

Comment: Ok. What is the result of print(response) ?

Comment: Its ok but know i have problem lower:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop\exercises\datagovv3.py", line 20, in <module>
    f.write(pagea)
ValueError: write to closed file

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line at the begin of your code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: how is this gonna help, the error is not even related to this, the error has a specific line and it is not about encoding

Comment: It will enable UTF-8 char (Greek letters ) to be interpreted correctly by python.

Comment: It gives  invalid syntax

Comment: @ronin512 well that is quite hard to get it to do really, also it won't fix anything, the issue is with `response` not being a string or a bytes-like object

Comment: It is modified like that  pagea=print(re.findall("(?!\")http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=περιβάλλον&page=*(?=\")", str(response))).It is downloading one page and gives the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pliroforiki-sox2\Desktop\exercises\datagovv3.py", line 18, in <module>
    f.write(pagea)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'